# How to draw multiple line graph by using matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, ekg

I want to create a Full 12 Leads EKG graph by using matplotlib in Python 2.7, so I had already wrote down some code to represent each lead (using subplot), but it have an issue about drawing a grid on sub-graph. Then I try to find a new solution to ploy all 12 leads within the same graph like this picture below

[image]

I have the list of data like this....

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,....]
lead1 = [-39,-34,-36,-38,.... ]
lead2 = [-40,-44,-86,-28,.... ]
.
.
lead12 = [-30,-27,-80,-69,.... ]
```

Could you give me some example code or the direction of how to make that.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I recommend you to check the matplotlib gallery: http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html . This example using subplots might help you: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example, where all lines are plotted in the same axes, but offset by 3 units in y direction.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

s=3
x = np.linspace(0,10,2000)
a = np.sin(np.cumsum((np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=(len(x), 12))), axis=0))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    ax.plot(x, a[:,i]+s*i)

labels = ["PG{}".format(i) for i in range(a.shape[1])]
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,a.shape[1])*s)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
for t, l in zip(ax.get_yticklabels(), ax.lines):
    t.set_color(l.get_color())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir, I try this one it's good but I have an issue when I used np.sin

as your code 
a = np.sin(np.cumsum((np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=(len(x), 12))), axis=0))

I was changed to 
a = np.dstack((nlead1,nlead2,nlead3,nlead4,nlead5,nlead6,nlead7,nlead8,nlead9,nlead10,nlead11,nlead12))

the error was occurred like this below
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Could you give me some suggestion. Thank you again _/\_

Comment: Error messages can usually be taken seriously. The error tells you that x and y to plot do not have the same length. As e.g. `plt.plot([1,2,3],[1.2,1.1])` would not work, because the lists do not have the same length. You need to make sure this to be the case.

Comment: So I was changed x = np.linspace(0,200,5500) "5500" is the same amount size of value in each nlead1-12

Not sure the Square Brackets is over or not 

data =
[[[ -39   47   86 ..., -100  -77   -3]
  [ -34   50   85 ..., -101  -75   -1]
  [ -36   49   86 ..., -103  -77   -4]
  ..., 
  [   0    0    0 ...,    0    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ...,    0    0    0]
  [   0    0    0 ...,    0    0    0]]]